# How do you know if a data set is right for linear regression if it has multiple features?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, linear-regression

If it has one feature it's easy. Just graph it.

[image]

One of the records there looks like (18, 15). Simple. But if we have multiple features that adds more dimensions to the graph, right? So how can you visualize your data set and determine whether or not linear regression is applicable if you can't graph it?

By the way, I am aware there is a [whole cluster of algorithms](http://blogs.technet.com/b/machinelearning/archive/2015/05/20/choosing-a-learning-algorithm-in-azure-ml.aspx?linkId=14528609) to choose from and linear regression might not be the best fit for a particular problem. I'm asking from a *I'm learning this* perspective not a *what's the best way to do this* perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Linear Regression assumes your data is linear even in multiple dimensions. It wont be possible to visualize high dimensional data unless you use some methods to reduce the high dimensional data. PCA can do that but bringing it down to 2 dimensions won't be helpful.

You should do Cross validation on your model to see if you are getting a decent fit on the data. If not it means that Linear Regression is not good for your data. .

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate an error (For example mean squared error) that shows how well your model is performing on your data. You can compare this error with the error that you get when fitting the model to more complex functions. It is always important to have metrics to compare your models.

See also Andrew Ng's course on the topic of Linear Regression with multiple Variables:
https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/outline?module=6okke